# JQGrid showlink styling not working

Tags: php, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

I'm using JQGrid and need to create a hyperlink in one of my columns. I've used the predefined formatter for showlink and the hyperlink is working fine. However the visual is not looking nice as it is creating some sort of rectangle and has a large height value (see attached screenshot). I've tried to look in the JQGrid css (ui.jqgrid.css) to find the CSS properties to modify the style of the link but could not find how to do it.

Does anybody know how?

[image: Example of the JQGrid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've able to fix it by adding this line to my CSS.

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow a { outline-style: none; border:none; vertical-align: middle; height:auto; width:100%;}
```